# Specific Coloring of Cube with 3 colors

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, permutation-cycles

> What is the number of essentially different ways to paint the faces of a cube such that one face is red, two are blue, and the remaining three are green?
>
> Do this ‘by hand’ (which may be quicker) as well as by using the cycle index theorem, and compare your answers.

Using Burnside's Lemma, I calculated the cycle index for the faces of a cube and that turned out to be
\begin{align*}
            Z(G) = \frac{1}{24}(a_1^6+3a_1^2a_2^2+6a_1^2a_4+6a_2^3+8a_3^2)
\end{align*}
and with $n=3$, there are $57$ different ways to color the cube, but I'm not sure how to go from here.

Any help, tips, or a fully worked out solution would be appreciated!

Comment: I suspect the answer is smaller than that.  A blue face must share an edge with the red face.  Therefore, we can orient the cube so that the red face is facing us and a blue face is on the bottom.  That leaves four ways to place the other blue face.  However, even that may be too large since we have to consider symmetries.

Comment: What do you mean by essentially different? Lets say each face is numbered 1 to 6 does every possible combination count or are two combinations considered the same if the only difference is the way the cube is rotated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, we may use the multivariate generating function 
$$ Z_G(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4) = \frac{1}{24}(a_1^6+3a_1^2a_2^2+6a_1^2a_4+6a_2^3+8a_3^2)$$
by letting $a_i=r^i+b^i+ g^i$ for $i=1,\dots,4$. Then we extract the coefficient of $r^1b^2g^3$ which is just the number of ways, up to rotations, to paint the faces of the cube such that $1$ face is red, $2$ are blue, and $3$ are green. 
$$[r^1b^2g^3]Z_G=[r^1b^2g^3]\frac{a_1^6+3a_1^2a_2^2}{24}=[b^2g^3]\frac{6(g+b)^5+6(g+b)2(g^2b^2)}{24}
=\frac{6\binom{5}{2}+12}{24}=3.$$

Further explanation. We paint one face red and then we have two cases:

1) If the opposite side is blue then we can paint the remaining blue face in $1$ way: it is one of the four lateral faces.

2) If the opposite side is green then we can paint the four lateral faces in $2$ ways: alternating blue and green faces or two adjacent blue faces and two adjacent green faces.

The total number of ways is $1+2=3$.